# unable to extract data from list

Tags: classcastexception

this is a function that retrieves a result list from DB.

```
public List<util> deep(){
    Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT state,max(pop2010) from uscensuspopulationdata where state <> 0 ");
    List<util> l=   query.getResultList();  
    return l;
}
```

Class util:

```
public class  util{
    int state;
    int pop2010;

    public util(int state, int pop2010) {
        this.state = state;
        this.pop2010 = pop2010;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "util{" + "state=" + state + ", pop2010=" + pop2010 + '}';
    }
}
```

When I try to extract the values like this, I am getting a ClassCastException:

```
List<util> l =  handle.deep();
for (util u : l) {
    out.print(u); 
}
```

Comment: Is the list returned by getResultList() of type <util>?

Comment: Nope.. return data of type List

Comment: Then that's your problem. When you're using the foreach loop, it's trying to cast objects in your list to objects of type `util` which is probably not possible. Find out what specific type the list is from the source code and then make a function or a factory class to take the elements from the list and make your own.

Comment: since the query returns a List, I decided not to use my util. Now, how do I retrieve the values in the list. i.e List l = handle.deep(); how do I print the values in the list?

Comment: @user1736333 is `uscensuspopulationdata` the name of a standalone table or a table associated to an `@Entity` ?

Comment: Now, please tell me how to print the value from a list. I am sure that query.getResultList() return a List. So I want to know how to extract values from List

Comment: @user1736333 And which entity is that? your `util` class?

Comment: no.. class uscensuspopulationdata

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of `util` objects you should be able to use the following query:

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT new util(state,max(pop2010)) from uscensuspopulationdata where state <> 0 ");
List<util> l = query.getResultList();
```

Where you call the constructor of util. This use case is specified [here in the HQL docu](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select).

If `uscensuspopulationdata` is a mapped Entity you also shouldn't use a `NativeQuery` but you can just use `getEntityManager().createQuery(...)`.

Finally, it is considered good style in java to capitalize the first letter of a class.